# How to display 3 items of array in single run in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Suppose the array has ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "fbf", "fddg","jpt1","jpt2","jpt3","jpt4"] The how can we display the above array like below ?

```
    <div>
       <span>Volvo</span>
       <span>BMW</span>
       <span>Toyota</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <span>fbf</span>
       <span>fddg</span>
       <span>jpt1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <span>jpt2</span>
       <span>jpt3</span>
       <span>jpt4</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chunk` method in collections class (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-chunk):

```
$collection = collect(["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "fbf", "fddg","jpt1","jpt2","jpt3","jpt4"]);
 
$chunks = $collection->chunk(3);
 
$chunks->all();
```

Comment: why change to the collection and use its Helper method while PHP itself has [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)